# Using isometric group to describe E7.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, isometry

I read John C. Baez's paper, The Octonions, and I am wondering the following statement: $$E_7\simeq Isom(\mathbb{(H\otimes O)P}^2).$$ In his contents, I can only figure out $$E_7\hookrightarrow Isom(\mathbb{(H\otimes O)P}^2),$$ but the other side is unclear for me. So how to contribute the inclusion on the other side? Or are there any references to this question?

Answer (score 1):

John C. Baez is giving the reference [6] for the proof in the section on $E_7$.
Reference [6] is the book by Arthur L. Besse, Einstein Manifolds, Springer, Berlin, 1987, pp. $313-316$. 
Actually, the quateroctonionic projective plane here is defined by
$$
(\mathbb{H }\otimes \mathbb{O})\mathbb{P}^2 = E_7 /((Spin(12) \times Sp(1))/\mathbb{Z}_2).
$$

Comment: 1. Doesn't the reference John C. Baez gave is a table of Lie algebras?
2. The quateroctonic projective plane does exactly defined in this way, so we can have the inclusion I described in my question. But I cannot figure out the other side.

Comment: John C. Baez writes explicitly after this definition: "It then turns out [6] that
$E_7\cong Isom((\mathbb{H }\otimes \mathbb{O})\mathbb{P}^2)$. So have a look at $[6]$.